# Untrusted Certs on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku

I'm not very learned on ssl and certs in general as I have only recently started "really" working with them and understanding them. I have an issue.

I'm shipping a library for android which connects to a specific domain "derp.com". Each of my customers get a subdomain to access with the library. EG "customer.derpy.com"

So working with https on android can be a pain but its not the end of the world. I'm having issues where my cert isnt being trusted by all of the devices using the https of the server.
I suspect this is why:

```
heroku certs --app my-app
Endpoint                  Common Name(s)                Expires               Trusted
------------------------  ----------------------------  --------------------  -------
cdepy412532.herokussl.com  *.derp.com, derp.com  2013-04-05 22:36 UTC  False
```

The certificate is being marked as untrusted. I suspect this is the cause of the issue as the devices are complaining that they cant verify the certificate. Why would this be?

---

The certificate is issued by a ca. I think its either rapidssl or geotrust.

Comment: Is this a self generated certificate or a certificate issued by a [CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority)?

Comment: @rubish Question has been updated. It was issue by a CA

Comment: I am also using the rapidssl certificate and do not see any such issue. I remember chaining CA certificate to the issued certificate. Did you do any such thing?

Answer (score 5):

I do hate answering my own question and would rather delete it but this may help someone else.

The issue in my case is that I had forgotten to combine the intermediate cert with the root cert.

This tutorial by [Ryan McGeary](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2011/09/16/how-to-add-a-dnsimple-ssl-certificate-to-heroku/) was a great help.

My only advice is make sure you have the intermediary certs (pem or crt), root certs(pem or crt) and private key(key) from your boss or whoever received them. If you do not have all of these then you will get an untrusted cert on heroku.

Comment: People: don't hate answering your own question. The worst thing is when you can only find 1 SO question, and the OP never returns to answer it :)